# Is it possible to hide the date and time and ip from Mobile Carrier

Tags: android, ios, privacy

I want to build an app that user can use anonymously without the date/time they visited a website to be known and without their IP address to be know by the mobile carriers(mobile network operators) who provide them internet using sim cards.

Is that possible?
If yes how can I achieve that for IOS development and Android development (tools I can implement :coding)

I really wants everything about the user to be anonymous even the usage of the app itself(opening and closing if the os keeps track of that) to not be logged somewhere).

Comment: What you have done till now ? Instead of asking how to do it, try something then ask about errors.

Comment: I want just a tip of guidance... I don't think stackoverflow is all about doing something then show but it is also about sharing experience to help other make good decision...actually I am planning the project(choosing the right way to follow).

Comment: well isn't meta or another part of this site more suitable for this question then as you are asking for a tool?

Comment: I want to implement the tool with code... it not a separate tool and this is all about building the app by coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First part, mobile carriers:* They will always know which server you are connecting to, because it's them who establish this connection. 
You'll have to build up a proxy server, and tunnel the real destination (encrypted) through this proxy. So the carrier will only see the proxy, not the destination. Similar to TOR.

*Second part, usage of the app*: Since you cannot influence what the OS on the phone is logging, you'll just have to create your own operating system and install it on the devices, or - maybe much more easy - develop your own mobile phone (hardware) which then runs any operating system you want (since you'll have to write it on your own, too).

Please keep us informed about your progress.